# Validar varios campos solo con una validación con reactive forms

Tags: javascript, angular, formularios

Tengo esta estructura, la cual tiene un `input` y un `radio button`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código de validación para el primer campo, me funciona

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d5sft6

Pero como ven en el ejemplo funciona para `reteFuente`, si lo quiero hacer para las otras dos retenciones como seria posible, claro optimizando código y no repetir

Comment: Hola. Puedes poner el código directamente sin necesidad de poner la imagen. Eso ayudará a que te respondamos más rápidamente. Puedes hacer un ejemplo funcional minimo en [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com])? Para ayudarte con la solución.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, deje un ejemplo del código

Comment: Podrias poner tu codigo en la pregunta?

Comment: El código esta en el ejemplo en linea de stackblitz